# Cloning of div including events applied to the elements inside it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an effect on a `checkbox(id="yes")` which will enable a texbox( whose id is "string" )onclicking. I am able to clone the div. But this effect is not working after that. Can Any one help me out?

HTML:

```
<form id="form" name="myForm">
        <div id="duplicater">
        <div id="duplicate">
        <label>Machine</label>
        <select>Select<option>Opt1</option></select>
        &nbsp;
        <label>Connection Type</label>
        <select><option>Select Connection Type</option>
        </select>&nbsp;
        <label>Command To Test</label><input type="text" value="command" />&nbsp;
        <label>Validate</label><input type="checkbox" name="yes" value="yes" id="yes" 

        onclick="enableDisable()">&nbsp;
        <label>Validate String</label><input type="text" id="string" name="string" size="10" 

        disabled></div></div>
        <input type="button" value="+" class="add">
        </form>
```

JS CODE:

```
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function(){

      $(".add").click(function () {

        var c=$('#duplicate').clone(true,true);

        $('#duplicater').append(c);
        $('#yes').append(function() {
         return $('#yes').click(enabledisable);
    })


    });
    });
    function enableDisable() { 
      if(document.myForm.yes.checked){ 
         document.myForm.string.disabled = false; 
      } else { 
         document.myForm.string.disabled = true; 
      } 
    } 
    window.onload = enableDisable;
    </script>
```

Comment: For clarity, can you double check that all relevant HTML is in there? I think you may have missed a line or two. (As an element appears to be cut in half.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use same id twice as per the w3c recommendation. and If you use it javascript/jquery will always refer the first element in the document.

So update the code and use classes instead of Ids

```
<label>Validate</label><input type="checkbox" name="yes" value="yes" class="validate-yes">&nbsp;
<label>Validate String</label><input type="text" class="validate-string" name="validate-string" size="10" disabled>
```

and use this js code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add").click(function () {
        var c=$('.duplicate').clone(true,true);
        $('#duplicater').append(c);
    });
    $('#form').on('click', '.validate-yes', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')){
          $(this).parent().find('.validate-string').prop('disabled', false);
        } else {
          $(this).parent().find('.validate-string').prop('disabled', true);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Check the updated code and you may also refer this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/BSh9c/ for example

Answer (score 0):

Check [jQuery Clone Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/clone/#clone-withDataAndEvents-deepWithDataAndEvents)

```
.clone( [withDataAndEvents ] [, deepWithDataAndEvents ] )
withDataAndEvents (default: false)
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data should be copied along with the elements. The default value is false. *In jQuery 1.5.0 the default value was incorrectly true; it was changed back to false in 1.5.1 and up.
deepWithDataAndEvents (default: value of withDataAndEvents)
Type: Boolean
A Boolean indicating whether event handlers and data for all children of the cloned element should be copied. By default its value matches the first argument's value (which defaults to false).
```

Also Please see [Event Deligation](http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate) and Use [**jQuery ON**](https://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind Events